# DRF: how to join many-to-many field into a string in json

Tags: react-native, django-rest-framework, expo

models.py

```
class SalesPerson(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    office = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    leader = models.ForeignKey(SalesPerson, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True,related_name='leader')    
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Product)    
    sales_person = models.ManyToManyField(SalesPerson)
```

serializers.py

```
class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    leader_name= serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='leader.name')
    location_name= serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='location.name')
    product = serializers.SlugRelatedField(read_only=True, slug_field='name', many=True)    
    sales_person = serializers.SlugRelatedField(read_only=True, slug_field='name', many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'leader_name', 'location_name', 'product', 'sales_person')

class SPSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    projects = ProjectSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, source='project_set')
    office_name= serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='office.city')
    class Meta:
        model = SalesPerson
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'office_name', 'email', 'projects')
```

result:

```
{
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Angela",
        "office_name": "NSW Sydney",
        "email": "angela@angela.com",
        "projects": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "title": "Mall Orchid",
                "leader_name": "Boris",
                "product": [
                    "Split wall mounted"
                ],
                "sales_person": [
                    "Angela",
                    "Boris",
                    "David"
                ],                
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "title": "Mall Petunia",
                "leader_name": "Boris",
                "product": [
                    "Split duct"
                ],
                "sales_person": [
                    "Angela",
                    "Boris",
                    "David"
                ],                
            },            
        ]
    },
```

I am going to consume the json using react native

I know how to iterate over "projects"

However, I want to avoid iterating over "sales_person" to make rendering the array simpler

So I am sure I have to make the sales_person into a string but after googling for many hours today, I can't find an answer

I am hoping to do this in Django Rest Framework and not in Expo React Native, if possible

So in short, I want to make the result like this:

```
{
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Angela",
        "office_name": "NSW Sydney",
        "email": "angela@angela.com",
        "projects": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "title": "Mall Orchid",
                "leader_name": "Boris",
                "product": [
                    "Split wall mounted"
                ],
                "sales_person": "Angela", "Boris", "David",                
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "title": "Mall Petunia",
                "leader_name": "Boris",
                "product": [
                    "Split duct"
                ],
                "sales_person": "Angela", "Boris", "David",                
            },            
        ]
    },
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer

I am writing it for my own future reference

```
class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    leader_name= serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='leader.name')
    location_name= serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='location.city')
    product = serializers.SlugRelatedField(read_only=True, slug_field='name', many=True)
    sales_person = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_sales_person')
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'leader_name', 'location_name', 'product', 'sales_person')

    def get_sales_person(self, obj):
        return ', '.join([sales_person.name for sales_person in obj.sales_person.all()])
```